# Accessing shared folder (SMB) on android without any app

Tags: android, android-studio, shared, smb

Is there any way which i can access shared folder(SMB) on a local network on android without any external apps?

I actually want to program an android app which its resources(photos) are in that shared folder!

Comment: You have an `smb` tag for your post. So you can conclude: YES. Start reading!

Comment: Never done this SMB-thing, but a quick Google search shows a promising sample app, by Google itself. https://github.com/google/samba-documents-provider